# Change DB Password without app server restart - ATG

Tags: database, passwords, atg

I would like to know is there any thing that would let me change the DB password in ATG without bouncing the Application server

Comment: Do you mean the database password, used for the connection pool or the dyn/admin password that is also stored in the database?

Comment: I mean the actual db password. For security reasons, our db password expires  after certain period of time. To update those, we have to bring down the app server, change password and bounce it. Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Your ATG application will use the connection pool settings of your application server. So if the application server requires a restart for changing the password then you will need to restart. The alternative of having the connection string in your JTDataSource.properties file is not secure so won't help from an ATG point of view.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is good approach or not but you can define FakeXA for your application and whenever you want to change the password you just need to change it to the corresponding component.